# Append text inputs in multiple text boxes to the url and open the url link

Tags: javascript

How to modify this to add two text boxes value to the URL.

```
//to add append single input value.
function filter(){
    var myInput1 = document.getElementById('myInput1').value;
    var searchType="fileName"
    var appl="www.google.com/search/?"+searchType+"="+myInput1;
    console.log(appl);
    myInput1.href =appl;
    myInput1.innerHTML = myInput1.href;
    window.location = "www.google.com/search/?"+searchType+"="+myInput1;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show your latest non-working attempt at solving this problem. It is usually more instructive to see fixes to your code than to read someone else's solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an array that contains a map of parameters name and values, and then join everything together to get your query string, something like:

```js
var parameters = [
  [ "fileName", document.getElementById('myInput1').value ],
  [ "otherInput", document.getElementById('myInput2').value ]
];

var query = parameters.map(function(couple) {
  return couple.join("=");
}).join("&");

// if you can use ES6 can be shorter, like:
// var query = parameter.map(couple => couple.join("=")).join("&");

var url = "www.google.com/search/?" + query;
```